# react-form: How to use multiple forms in combineReducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Disclaimer: It is possible, that this question seems stupid because I might have overlooked anything obvious or self-evident in the docs. For now my reducer-setup looks like this:

```js
import editBlogEntryForm from './blog/editBlogEntryForm';
import login from './login'; // <-- a directory with index.js
import blog from './blog';   // <-- a directory with index.js

export default combineReducers({
    blog: blog,
    login: login,
    form: editBlogEntryForm
});
```

Where shall I put other forms in the future?
Learning more about seperating reducers, I moved the `blog` and `login` reducers into their own directories/files where I use reducer composition. But it seems I cannot move the `form` anywhere, it has to stay top-level, which does not make sense, if I later want to introduce a login-form or so. I hope I don't have to put everything into the same form-reducer, resulting in a quite big switch-statement?

I already tried moving the `form: editBlogEntryForm` "down" into the `blog` reducer, but the form stops working/updating then.

Here is the `reduxForm` call in my container-component for the form:

```js
EditBlogEntryFormContainer = reduxForm({
    form: 'EditBlogEntryForm',
    validate
})(EditBlogEntryFormContainer);
```

Can someone please point me the right direction please?

From the redux-form-docs http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/GettingStarted.md/ I got this:

> Note that, by default, the key used to pass the redux-form reducer to
>   combineReducers should be named form. Although there is support for
>   custom key names, see getFormState config for more details.

Comment: A comment on down-votes would be nice (especially, if it's done seconds after the posting), so I could improve my questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Thijs Steel and his pointing me to the `getFormState` prop of `reduxForm()` (see docs http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/), I came to a solution that is working with verbose form name and state-location. Though I still cannot follow the docs saying about `getFormState`:

> This functionality is rarely needed, and defaults to assuming that the
>   reducer is mounted under the form key.

I think we all want more than one form and form-reducer in our apps, so using `getFormState` rather seems the standard case to me. But still, I'm not sure, I might have missed anything obvious.

Solution is to change the connection of the form-component with the redux-form like this:

```js
EditBlogEntryFormContainer = reduxForm({
    form: 'EditBlogEntryForm',
    getFormState: (state) => state.blog.editBlogEntryForm, // <-- your form reducer location
    validate
})(EditBlogEntryFormContainer);
```

So any form can have its state from any location of the app's state making multiple forms possible.

Not using getFormState is defaulting to using the `form`-reducer from top-level of the state, which would result into this:

```js
EditBlogEntryFormContainer = reduxForm({
    form: 'EditBlogEntryForm',
    getFormState: (state) => state.form,  // <-- default of reduxForm
    validate
})(EditBlogEntryFormContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to add another form in the Future you could call it form2: ... (Or some other, more apropriate name).

When you moved the form down, did you also use combinereducers to combine the lower level ones?. If so, bear in mind that to acces the state you would need to do state.blog.form and state.blog.main

Comment: Renaming the identification (for example from `form` to `blogEntryForm`) was the first thing I tried. The form stops working then. Maybe the reduxForm call in my container-component is wrong (see additional code in OP)?

Comment: Are you Passing down the store using a provider? Can you show where you use the state/ mapstatetoprops function?

Comment: Thanks for your time. `mapStateToProps` is mapping only one object `currentEntry: state.blog.currentEntry`  which I pass down into the form to prefill it (using `initialize`). Do I have to map more?

Comment: And when you combined it with the form, you changed that right?

Comment: Everything is working OK with that `mapStateToProps` and to answer your comment before: yes, I'm using  `<Provider>` to have store available. I just need a way to have more than just one redux-form available (as written in the docs, it should be mounted as `form`).

Comment: So the getFormState property is basically like the mapStateToProps function. I'm on my phone right now so typing it out is rather hard, but i'll try

Comment: getFormState: (state)=> {state.blog.form},

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143524/discussion-between-thijs-steel-and-christof-kalin).